# Float div in top left without putting it on the first line

Tags: css, html, semantic-markup

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LGVKm/1/

For semantic and SEO reasons (and because i like it better) i want to put the aside element after my content in the document flow.
But I want the aside to float left from the text, at the top.
Any way to make that possible using css? Tried a lot.

I can always put the aside before the text div, but that puts it before the important content. Which i do not want. Or should i just swallow my pride and go the easy route. Would it matter to the search-engines. I imagine the aside element has a lower priority... nut not sure how html5-aware the spiders are...

And another semantic thing: I doubted using an article tag for the content, but i'm not sure about it. It's not like it's going to be distributed. Could replace the section for article, but section made more sense in my mind.

Comment: +1 for being semantic-aware. Perhaps, just perhaps, a **tiny** bit too aware :)

Comment: why not float the div right - http://jsfiddle.net/LGVKm/7/

Comment: @Jawad Try making the window horizontally smaller.

Comment: @NovapaX are you okay with using some JavaScript?

Comment: That is the default behaviour of float. Alternatively you could use positioning. http://jsfiddle.net/LGVKm/23/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an CSS3 solution for this may be that's help you. For this you can use **flexible** property.

```
.parent{
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: box;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-direction: reverse;
    -webkit-box-direction: reverse;
    box-direction: reverse;
}
.parent div { 
    border: 1px solid blue;
    -moz-box-flex: 2;
    -webkit-box-flex: 2;
    box-flex: 2;
}
aside {
    width: 4em; 
    border: 1px solid red;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/LGVKm/26/

Read this https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/04/the-css-3-flexible-box-model/

Comment: interesting. But the fiddle, the aside is still below the div. missed some code?

Comment: @sandeep bhai sirf mozilla k liye thodi na chahea ? ie ka kya ?

Comment: @SACHIN: Wow. we need to translate the hindi/urdu!

Comment: @Jawad ha ha ha ok. SANDEEP this is only for mozilla what about ie ?

Comment: @SACHIN i know that but this an suggestion from my side may be that's help OP or future users. it's work in all modern browsers.

Comment: @sandeep: You are right. My bad. I checked in IE9(gulp!) but it works in FF. +1 for filling my lack of knowledge.

Comment: @sandeep: That's indeed exactly what I was looking for. Unless someone comes up with a better answer that works in older browsers I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: and as always: here's the Javascript lib to make it work in IE: https://github.com/doctyper/flexie or just use Mordernizr or something.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like:

```
float:right; width: 70%
```

To the `div` element.

Comment: You don't know that the `aside` will only take `30%`.

Comment: I can't give the content a width, the asides width is in pixels, the total width grows with the window.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/LGVKm/10/ try this.You will get your solution

Comment: Nope, this one doesn't work when resizing the window, either.

Comment: you can add width in  "div" in % then
}

Answer (score 0):

Floating the elements left/right works, as long as you define their widths and have a container with a defined width. I altered your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LGVKm/29/) to reflect what I mean.

Comment: This works for other measurements than px as well, but you should try to stick with one measurement and not mix px/em/percentage.

Comment: thanks, the widht of aside changes based on media query... (a lot of other stuff too). I can't define the width of both the div and the aside.

Comment: @NovapaX Then I'm afraid it can't be done unless you do it with positioning, because of how floating works. These kind of things get extremely tricky when you want to keep things as semantic as possible.

Answer (score 0):

### Layout

Depending on the overall structure (like navigation or web page heading), you could use absolute positioning. I think it might work here (`relative;` for the container, `absolute` for one of the columns and `margin` for the other one).

The `float:right;` method would work too. If you don't like the resizing behavior, you could take a look at CSS [Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/), to adjust the layout when the viewport changes.

---

### `article` or `section`?

> And another semantic thing: I doubted using an article tag for the content, but i'm not sure about it. It's not like it's going to be distributed. Could replace the section for article, but section made more sense in my mind.

`article` would be the right choice, if that content (in the scope of "Our Work") is a cohered text that would make sense to be read on its own.

It doesn't matter if it's going to *be* distributed, it only matters if it *could* typically be distributed without losing its meaning.

If it is the only content (= the main content) on the page, `article` would be the right choice most of the time. Only if there would be no other sectioning elements (like `nav` or `aside`) on the top-level, you shouldn't use a separate `article` but use the `body` directly instead.

---

### Some other notes:

You could (and I think you should) enclose the two "Sub" blocks in explicit `section` elements

You could (and I think you should) give the `aside` an explicit heading. Hide it visually (so that it still gets read by screen-readers) if it is unwanted in the design.

Only use `figure` if it matches the [definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-figure-element.html#the-figure-element). Don't use it for *all* cases where you need an image with a caption.

At the moment, your `aside` is "related" to the `section` (or `article`, if you like). Is this intended? Otherwise you should add it as a `body` descendant (so it would be "related" to the whole web page).

Comment: Late reaction... sorry! It's a one-page desing, with multiple parts like 'what we do', 'our work' and 'contact'. Each have an aside. The asides are indeed related to that part, but absolutely not 'necessary content' (I'm even thinking about hiding them in the mobile version) If you want you can take a look at www.oosterwijkbrandpreventie.nl/test/ (it's going to be public facing soon anyway...) It's my test directory, so is breaks... a lot!